# Best practice to merge config files and deploy them

Tags: deployment, configuration, merge, web-deployment

On a regular base, we do some changes (modify or add) on our web application config file. Every time someone adds a new config line, he has to tell the team that he was adding a new config part to the global config. We have a scaffolding config under version control. Is there a smart way to merge the new config template with your existing config file? Does somebody know a tool to automating this process? We have also an testing and staging server, where this changes also have to be pushed on automatically (or raise a trigger if some manual changes are needed).

Comment: What platform is this on? What IDE?

Comment: It's on a *nix based plattform. Not realy IDE depended. A command line script would be also possible.